# Group by keys and create a list of respective values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to convert my dictionary to this format. I have tried using groupby but not able to achieve the expected format.

```
input = [
         {'algorithms': 'BLOWFISH', 'dcount': 5.8984375},
         {'algorithms': 'AES-256', 'dcount': 5.609375},
         {'algorithms': 'AES-256', 'dcount': 9.309375},
         {'algorithms': 'RSA', 'dcount': 8.309375},
         {'algorithms': 'BLOWFISH','dcount': 6.309375}
        ]
```

Expected output:

```
  output = [
  {
    name: "BLOWFISH",
    data: [5.8984375,6.309375]
  },
  {
    name: "AES-256",
    data: [5.609375,9.309375]
  },
  {
    name: 'RSA',
    data: [8.309375]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort `input` before [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will work:

> The operation of `groupby()` is similar to the `uniq` filter in Unix. It
> generates a break or new group every time the value of the key
> function changes (which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted
> the data using the same key function). That behavior differs from
> SQL’s GROUP BY which aggregates common elements regardless of their
> input order.

```
from itertools import groupby
import json

input = [
   {
        "algorithms": "BLOWFISH",
        "dcount": 5.8984375
   },
   {
        "algorithms": "AES-256",
        "dcount": 5.609375
   },
   {
        "algorithms": "AES-256",
        "dcount": 9.309375
   },
   {
        "algorithms": "RSA",
        "dcount": 8.309375
   },
   {
        "algorithms": "BLOWFISH",
        "dcount": 6.309375
   }
]

output = [
    {
        "name": k,
        "data": [d["dcount"] for d in g]
    } 
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(input, key=lambda d: d["algorithms"]),
                        key=lambda d: d["algorithms"])
]

print(json.dumps(output, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "AES-256",
        "data": [
            5.609375,
            9.309375
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "BLOWFISH",
        "data": [
            5.8984375,
            6.309375
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "RSA",
        "data": [
            8.309375
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on how unpacking is done here for my understanding?

Comment: List comprehension over the group by results (in which the input needs to be sorted for these to be correct), additionally also rename the `algorithm` key to `name`, and use another list comprehension for each value for the `data` key. Basically, look up "list-comprehension" on google.

Answer (score 0):

Had a go at this for you:

```
data = [
         {'algorithms': 'BLOWFISH', 'dcount': 5.8984375},
         {'algorithms': 'AES-256', 'dcount': 5.609375},
         {'algorithms': 'AES-256', 'dcount': 9.309375},
         {'algorithms': 'RSA', 'dcount': 8.309375},
         {'algorithms': 'BLOWFISH', 'dcount': 6.309375}
        ]

series = []
firstRun = True

for i in data:
    found = False
    if firstRun:
        series.append(
            {
                'name': i['algorithms'],
                'data': [i['dcount']]
            }
        )
        firstRun = False
    else:
        for j in series:
            if i['algorithms'] == j['name']:
                j['data'].append(i['dcount'])
                found = True
            else:
                continue
        if not found:
            series.append(
                {
                    'name': i['algorithms'],
                    'data': [i['dcount']]
                }
            )
```

This should give you your desired output:

```
>>> print(series)
[{'name': 'BLOWFISH', 'data': [5.8984375, 6.309375]}, {'name': 'AES-256', 'data': [5.609375, 9.309375]}, {'name': 'RSA', 'data': [8.309375]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like a more concise code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with no additional module:

```
def group_algorithms(input_list):
    out = []
    names = []
    for algorithms in input_list:
        if algorithms['algorithms'] in names:
            out[names.index(algorithms['algorithms'])]["data"].append(algorithms['dcount'])
        else:
            out.append({"name": algorithms['algorithms'],
                        "data": [algorithms['dcount']]})
            names.append(algorithms['algorithms'])
    return out
```